# Assign node to one domain only

Tags: domain-access

I've installed domain access module and all its submodules.
I have two domains (both set already) and I would like to assign node to one of these domain only.

I set the proper domain in node edit form, but it really doesn't affect the anonymous user permissions, because ALL users can view this node from all domains.

[image]

Devel node access displays on the node page something like below:
[image]

I checked user permissions as well and everything looks pretty good there.

How do I configure this module to access node only from the right domain?

--- edit ---

after change suggested in one answer it looks like

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be good idea to switch to English before making a screenshot. And by the way you want that restriction to apply for all nodes with domain set?

Comment: '' Yes. There is an option to set where the node should be published (while node editing).

Comment: I admit I don't remember details, but I believed that, if set, it should simply work. If you are not messing with it in any way, maybe it's a bug in module? Edit: Just seen the answer below and it looks like you did.

Comment: OK, so now problem is with second row. It is supposed to be 0, but it's 1. Try to rebuild permissions and test again.

Comment: There is no access after permission rebuild from any domain now.

Comment: If you don't @ mention me I'm not being notified. Anyway, if you could be so nice and put updated screenshot in your question? Now domain access should show 0 0 1, right?

Comment: @Mołot  devel says "Domain Access -- False: Only allows content from the active domain (dev.drupal) or from all affiliates.", but I try to access the node from this domain. Maybe it doesn't work on localhost?

Comment: It *should* work on localhost. But maybe it's a bug that prevents it? You can use `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` in *NIX, `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` in modern Windowses) to virtually attach a domain(s) to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Mołot I have virtual hosts set.

Comment: So it's not a localhost problem, Drupal and Domain Access never touch IP directly.

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshot above there is a "Send to all Affiliates" checkbox and then checkboxes for each individual domain. If you leave the "Send to all Affiliates" checked it overrides the individual checkboxes.

So, the solution for you is to uncheck the "Send to all Affiliates" checkbox.

Comment: It doesn't help. I can still (as anonymous) see node from `dev.drupal/content/testestestest` and `test.drupal/content/testestestest`

Comment: @daroPL are you sure you have cleared all caches along the line? From Drupal's to bowser's?

Comment: @Mołot yes, I've done it.

Comment: @daroPL so please update your screenshots to reflect current state of your configuration and node assess flow.

Comment: @Mołot attached.